Postgresql Left Join via intersecting geometry columns leads to wrong Sum and correction has bad performance
I have two tables with the following structure and a lot of data:
CREATE TABLE lines
(
    "Id" text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    "ProjectId" text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    "Geometry" geography(LineString,4326) NOT NULL,
    "Type" text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    "Length" numeric,
    "Depth" numeric,
    "Source" text COLLATE pg_catalog."default"
)

CREATE TABLE corners
(
    "Id" integer NOT NULL,
    "CornerNumber" integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    "Polygon" geography(Polygon,4326) NOT NULL
)

Indexes are already created:
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_lines_geometry ON lines USING GIST ("Geometry");
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_corners_polygon ON corners USING GIST ("Polygon");

I want a sum over the lines."Length" column grouped by
corners."CornerNumber", 
lines."Type", 
lines."Depth", 
lines."Source"

joined over the geograpy columns.
This worked until the lines were intersecting with multiple records from corners.
select 
    c."CornerNumber", 
    l."Type",
    l."Depth", 
    l."Source", 
    sum(l."Length") as Length, 
from lines l 
left join corners c on ST_Intersects(l."Geometry", c."Polygon") 
where l."ProjectId" = '12345'
group by 
    c."CornerNumber", 
    l."Type",
    l."Depth", 
    l."Source" 
;

This obviously does not sum correct as the left join could potentially return multiple records. I tried to correct this but the performance dropped and the queries take double the time.
select 
    c."CornerNumber", 
    l."Type",
    l."Depth", 
    l."Source", 
    sum(l."Length") as Length, 
from lines l 
left join lateral (
    select cj."CornerNumber" 
    from corners cj 
    where ST_Intersects(l."Geometry", cj."Polygon") 
    group by cj."CornerNumber"
) c on true 
where l."ProjectId" = '12345'
group by 
    c."CornerNumber", 
    l."Type",
    l."Depth", 
    l."Source" 
;

Depending on the project and number of records per project the wrong queries take 1-4 seconds. With the correction the queries take 2-9 seconds.
After trying different things i came across the idea two use partition:
WITH filtered_lines AS (
    SELECT 
        "Id", "Type", "Depth", "Source", "Length", "Geometry"
    FROM 
        lines 
    WHERE 
        "ProjectId" = '12345'
),
intersected_lines AS (
    SELECT 
        fl."Type", 
        fl."Depth", 
        fl."Source", 
        fl."Length", 
        cj."CornerNumber",
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY fl."Id", fl."Type", fl."Depth", fl."Source" ORDER BY cj."CornerNumber") as row_num
    FROM 
        filtered_lines fl
    LEFT JOIN 
        corners cj 
    ON 
        ST_Intersects(fl."Geometry", cj."Polygon")
)
SELECT 
    "CornerNumber", 
    "Type", 
    "Depth", 
    "Source", 
    SUM("Length") as "TotalLength"
FROM 
    intersected_lines
WHERE 
    row_num = 1
GROUP BY 
    "CornerNumber", 
    "Type", 
    "Depth", 
    "Source"
;

This is slower than the first query but faster than the second query.
For a Project with average records i get following values:

First query: 3.6 - 4.1 seconds
Subselect query: 7.2 - 7.6 seconds
Partition query: 3.8 - 4.8 seconds

Is there a faster join possible with the correct sum over the length column? Maybe even faster than the partition query?

Use btree_gist to add "ProjectId" before "Geometry". Right now it probably uses your bare GiST index to search the whole RTree to find way more shapes than it needs to, then filters that to only leave your target project '12345'. If they were both indexed, it'd go to 12345's branch and find its own tree, way smaller and faster to search.
IF you're really interested in all lines whether they intersect any corner or not, you might want to cluster using that, to make the likely unavoidable seq scan a bit faster:
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_lines_geometry ON lines 
  USING GIST ("ProjectId", "Geometry")
  INCLUDE("Type", "Depth", "Source", "Length");

CLUSTER lines USING idx_lines_geometry;

Alternatively, you could also speed up that filter by adding include("ProjectId") to what you already have. In either case, you can use include to add all columns you request from the tables as inert payload on the index, to make them covering indexes and save yourself heap fetches, switching fast index scans to even faster index-only scans:
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_corners_polygon ON corners 
  USING GIST ("Polygon")
  INCLUDE("CornerNumber");

Make sure to vacuum analyze lines; and vacuum analyze corners;.
These changes should speed up all 3 of your statements. You could probably restructure the last one to simply grab a distinct on() if you want each corner to get assigned only to a single line, but I don't think it'd be much different performance wise.
